# Flutter Image Picked from Gallery has Reduced Size - How to Maintain Original Size?

Tags: flutter, flutter-image, flutter-image-compress

I am facing an issue where the size of the picked image in the app is significantly smaller than the original image in the phone's gallery.

---

Original image `14.5 MB`
but after picking it, its `324 KB` without any quality setting.

---

In Document
[image]

in my flutter app
[image]

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
    // image_picker: ^0.8.7+1 
    // https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

    final imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedImage = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (pickedImage != null) {
      final originalImage = File(pickedImage.path);
      final imageSize = originalImage.lengthSync();
      
      setState(() {
        _image = originalImage;
        _imageSize = imageSize;
        _imageWidth = image.width;
        _imageHeight = image.height;
      });
    }
```

Could anyone please help me understand why and how its happening and how to pick images with original size?

Comment: The picker is `image_picker: ^0.8.7+1` from  https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Answer (score 0):

specify the imageQuality parameter when picking the image.

```
final pickedImage = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: 
ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 100,);
```

Comment: When picking an image from the gallery in Flutter, the size of the image might be reduced by default to optimize memory usage and performance. To maintain the original size of the image, you can use the image_picker package and specify the imageQuality parameter when picking the image.

Comment: Garbage answer, please provide reasonable source and response. The default image quality is already 100

Comment: From documentation : The `imageQuality` argument modifies the quality of the image, ranging from 0-100 where 100 is the original/max quality. If `imageQuality` is null, the image with the original quality will be returned.

Comment: Please provide the complete code for this page